# In flask-security-too, can a passwordless login token expire after first use?

Tags: authentication, token, flask-security, password-less

We've been using password-less login feature from flask-security for some time but we now discovered that login link can actually be used multiple times which is not ideal security-wise. I've spent some time reading through https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html trying to find a setting which would make login token invalid after first use but I only came across `SECURITY_LOGIN_WITHIN` option that sets the token's lifetime. What I would like would be:

- token made invalid once used
- token expired if not used within ..

Does flask-security provide such a config?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct - these tokens aren't one-time - but they are timed - so the token will expire if not used after SECURITY_LOGIN_WITHIN seconds (which is your second ask).

The newish feature - unified_signin provides a more flexible way of providing authentication - including email links (like passwordless) or one-time codes, SMS, authenticator app.

In unified_signin - all the codes are generated using passlibs TOTP - which are ALSO timed tokens - not truly one time. However - as documented here: https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#flask_security.Totp
you can implement the recommended counter persistence to ensure one-time use/no replays.

Answer (score 0):

app.config['SECURITY_LOGIN_WITHIN'] = "10 minutes"

is a good value.

If the link has expired, a new message is sent (flask-security-too)